# Power Query - Fetch data from PDF when files have different pages

Tags: pdf, powerquery

I am extracting data from multiple PDF files having a similar structure. Most of the PDF files have 2 Pages of data except one PDF which is having only one page.

Have created a query called Page001 and Page002 to get data from each page. Then appending both get combined data. This append query is working fine except for PDF which is having one page.

I am getting the below error for the Page002 query since there is no data on page 2.

Expression.Error: The key didn't match any rows in the table.
Details:
Key=
Id=Page002
Table=[Table]

Because of the above query append query is not working. Getting below error

An error occurred in the ‘Page002’ query. Expression.Error: The key didn't match any rows in the table.
Details:
Key=
Id=Page002
Table=[Table]

Kindly help in appending data something like below

if Page002 table is empty then the output will be Pagee001 else Table.Combine({Page001, Page002}).

Comment: You can use the `try otherwise` structure to check the error

Comment: Thanks Ricardo.... It's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the below query and worked

```
let<br/>
    Source = try Table.Combine({Page001, Page002}) otherwise Page001,<br/>
in<br/>
    Source
```